# How to access a relative path node higher than index.html

Tags: html, polymer, relative-path, polymer-1.0

I am serving my files on `localhost:` using `$ gulp serve`.

My file structure looks like this:

```
--- root/
   |--- firebase.json
   |--- app/
       |--- index.html
       |--- manifest.json
       |--- elements/
           |--- my-elements/
               |--- my-element.html
```

Inside `my-elements.html` I call two `<iron-ajax>` elements as follows:

my-elements.html

```
<iron-ajax id="manifest" url="../../manifest.json">
<iron-ajax id="firebase" url="../../../firebase.json">
```

### Problem

I can access the `manifest.json` file just fine. But when I try to access the `firebase.json` file, I get the following error:

Error message accessing firebase.json:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/firebase.json 404 (Not Found) iron-request.html:245
```

## Questions

> - What's going on?
> - What am I not understanding about relative paths?
> - Am I for some reason being blocked from accessing files higher then `index.html` using relative paths? (*Makes no sense to me.*)
> - How do I access firebase.json using a relative path in my `<iron-ajax> url` property? (*Or at all, for that matter.*)

Comment: Where do you host your system? At a hosting company, on a own server or local? Maybe your configruation doesn't allow access to any path outside of your "web root" (which is the folder with the index.html)

Comment: I think you need to move the firebase.json under the app/ folder and then reference to it with "../../firebase.json"

I assume the app/ folder is the highest folder the webserver can serve.

Comment: @MrK: You're counting wrong. Also, as I mentioned, I can access `manifest.json` just fine. And `firebase.json` is clearly one level higher than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you are being blocked, because the path you are using is perfectly valid.

And it kinda makes sense for your service provider to only make the app folder public.

Answer (score 0):

After further experimentation and analysis, I'm pretty sure here's what's happening...

When the files are created and saved locally on my machine, the web root is the `root/app/` directory. However, when the pages are served by gulp, the web root becomes `localhost:3000`. Since `localhost:3000` is the highest node accessible in the path, we can't access the other directories above it?

There are still some things this theory doesn't answer. Like why can we access the content of the other files we want to like that in `bower_components` and `node_modules` etc. But that answer might come another day.

**Edit:**
Looks like the answer to the questions remaining in the above paragraph are [found in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34143288/1640892) (and its question).

Looks like gulp is preparing a distribution directory (named `dist`) that reorganizes the files when served from Polymer Starter Kit that takes into account the path differential for at least the `bower_components` subdirectory.