# Understanding Polymer 1.x Polymer Starter Kit file structure as it relates to bower_components imports

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

In the Polymer Starter Kit, every reference to the `bower_components` subdirectory refers to a node just below the `app` directory. However, (at least in my version of PSK) the `bower_components` subdirectory is one level up from the `app` directory. In other words, the `bower_components` subdirectory is actually located in the project root directory.

Am I just miscounting my directory nodes? Or does this have something to do with how `gulp` and maybe `vulcanize` work? Or is it something else altogether that I'm not understanding?

For example, in `index.html` there is this script tag:

index.html

```
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
```

which suggests the `bower_components` directory is at the same level as `index.html`. But it's not. `bower_components` is actually one level up.

Same for element imports.

Comment: Yup, that's how PSK is set up. I don't like it either. I think the devs like bower_components to be in the same directory as node modules. Gulp serve transforms the path links such that bower_components seem like they're served from the `app` directory, and the `app` directory seem like the root. For me I just make a copy of bower components into `app` and serve it using python or something during development. No idea what gives though.

Comment: @zerodevx it's more about everything in the `app` folder should be *yours* than it is about having the dependency folders in the same place. I think that's important.

Answer (score 0):

Compilation of responses from [Polymer Slack Site](https://polymer.slack.com/messages/general):

Response #1:

> yeah, gulp basically builds everything into a build and the web server serves the build folder instead of the project. I don’t remember what’s the name of the build folder in starter kit in particular, but for most project it works as I described

Response #2:

> it’s specific to PSK. The local server mounts that directory and serves it as if it were inside `app`. I just sent in a PR to change this because it’s confusing